# fgetcsv не могу получить результаты из первого столбца

Tags: php

Я хочу получать значения из столбцов по заголовку столбца. У меня получается получить любое, кроме первого. Почему так? Выдает ошибку

> Notice: Undefined index: ZIP

```
$file_name="http://www.omniva.ee/locations.csv";

$fp = fopen($file_name, 'r');

$head = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"');

while($column = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"'))
{
    $column = array_combine($head, $column);
    echo $column['ZIP']; // не получаю
    echo $column['NAME']; // получаю

}
```

Comment: добавьте пример записи из csv файла, возможно ошибка в нём, а не в коде.

Comment: ссылка в коде на файл рабочая. часть файла сюда добавил если удобней http://pastebin.com/fWdw2Xvd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working version

```
$file_name="http://www.omniva.ee/locations.csv";

$fp = fopen($file_name, 'r');

$head = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"');
$head[0] = 'ZIP'; # это фикс!
while($column = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"'))
{
    $column = array_combine($head, $column);
    echo $column['ZIP']; // не получаю
    echo $column['NAME']; // получаю

}

?>
```

Comment: еще можно сохранить фaил с BOM -utf8

Answer (score 2):

Все просто. В самом начале файла есть два "левых байта". это так называемый [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Есть много способов их удалить, но думаю, что в Вашем случае подойдет самое простое решение

```
$file_name="http://www.omniva.ee/locations.csv";

$fp = fopen($file_name, 'r');

$head = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"');
$head[0] = 'ZIP'; # это фикс!
while($column = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"'))
{
    $column = array_combine($head, $column);
    echo $column['ZIP']; // не получаю
    echo $column['NAME']; // получаю

}
```

BTW, поле zip есть, только выглядит так `<U+FEFF>ZIP`.

Comment: ваш фикс у меня не работает

Comment: Вставьте `print_r($column);` на место фикса и все станет явно.

Comment: Ой, не column, а head